# Are decoration type checks possible?

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to type check on possible decorators (the decorators introduced in TypeScript 5.0, not the legacy decorators). My initial thought would be that it is not possible, I did a lot of searching but I couldn't find any source which would give me the answer.

Say I have the following decorator:

```js
function EntityOnly<C, ET>(_target: undefined, context: ClassFieldDecoratorContext<C, ET>) {
  // Register this field in the context metadata.  
}
```

Now I describe a class which uses the decorator for some of it fields:

```js
class User {
  id: number = 0;
  username: string = '';
  @EntityOnly
  hashedPassword: any = {};
  @EntityOnly
  IBAN: string = '';
}
```

If I would want a variable of an union type consisting of all the keys of `User` that are a string I can achieve that like this:

```js
type IfAny<T, Y, N> = 0 extends (1 & T) ? Y : N;
type StringMembers<T> = keyof { [P in keyof T as T[P] extends string ? IfAny<T[P], never, P> : never]: any; };

// Will be of type: "username" | "IBAN"
let userStringMember: StringMembers<User>;
```

But now my question would be how could I do a similar thing to declare an union type consisting of keys referring to members that are decorated with the `EntityOnly` decorator?

Comment: It's impossible till https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881 resolved